# After switching brackets [] to list, would this be considered to be the same?

Tags: python

I commented out the list containing the odd numbers and added my_odds = list(range(1, 60, 2))
print(my_odds). I was wondering whats the difference between the list and the []? are they technically the same?

```
def first_code_from_headfirst():

   # odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55,
     #       57, 59]

    my_odds = list(range(1, 60, 2))
    print(my_odds)

    for el in range(5):
        right_this_minute = datetime.today().minute

        if right_this_minute in my_odds:
            print("this minute seems a little odd")

        else:
            print('not an odd minute.')
```

Comment: Yes, here it is ecactly the same.

Comment: given you do no override the `list` variable

Comment: Although if you use the brackets, it might work a bit faster, since then you load a list expression, instead of constructing a list based on the elements in the iterable.

Comment: `list(range(1, 60, 2))` returns the list you had.. The good thing about using `list(range(1, 60, 2))` is, say, if you want to change the step of your `range` to 3, you just have to change form `2` to `3`, whereas if you had the previous expressions, you'd have to change all items

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if the behaved the same. Thank you Willem van onsem. I was just curious thank you for your time. That's interesting that brackets can work a little faster.

Comment: ok thank you @RafaelC

Comment: The speed difference between the list literal and `list(range(…))` call is irrelevant here. `range()` is more readable, and if you don’t convert it to a list – just write `my_odds = range(1, 60, 2)` – the `right_this_minute in my_odds` check will be O(1) instead of O(n). But if you’re just trying to check if it’s odd, that’s `if right_this_minute % 2 == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `[]` and `list` is that one is syntactic construct and the other is function call. Which means:

```
import dis

def func():
    a = []

dis.dis(func)

  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

whereas:

```
def func():
    a = list()

dis.dis(func)

  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the former should be tiny bit faster as it does not have to search for the global name `list`. (This is for CPython 2.7.10)